# Force deluge to use VPN

Tags: apache, networking, vpn, iptables, bittorrent

I have set up Deluge daemon and web interface for Deluge on my Debian server. I also use Deluge as a thin client on my laptop (I connect to the Deluge daemon on the server through port **58846**).

I have set up a VPN (interface **ppp0**) which I want Deluge to use for torrenting. I manage to get Deluge to use this interface (given that it is up and running) after specifying this in the preferences section of Deluge. When I turn the VPN off (simulating that the VPN disconnects due to an error), Deluge falls back on the default **eth0** interface of my server (torrenting through this interface, which I don't want happening).

What I want, is to force Deluge to use **ppp0** for torrenting, making all torrenting stop, should the VPN connection at some point fail. At the same time I want to be able to access the Deluge daemon from my thin client through port **58846** on interface **eth0** (for controlling the daemon and adding torrents).

This is what I've tried so far:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 58846 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner deluge \! -o ppp0 -j REJECT
```

This doesn't work, and I assume it's because there's no port for Deluge to answer connections coming in on port 58846 because that would try to send an **OUTPUT** on an interface which is not **ppp0**.

Am I far away from a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Execute deluge, and any other application that's supposed to use the VPN, in a separate [network namespace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html), move ppp0 into that namespace after it starts up.

That way deluge will be isolated from eth0.

Comment: It still needs to send some data over eth0, the deluge daemon listens on port 58846 for incoming connections (and needs to respond appropriately over eth0 as well).